# wp_mail function is not sending an email. How do I fix it?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

Unable to send an email using the below wp_mail function. How do I fix it?

```
wp_mail($email_address,'Welcome!','Your password'.$password);
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing some required elements. As noted on the WordPress Codex (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail), you need to have at least a "to", a "subject" and a "message".

The Codex example:

```
<?php wp_mail( 'me@example.net', 'The subject', 'The message' ); ?>
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the "password" part of your example, but you might not be using the right WordPress function?